# Realtime database login not working using DatabaseReference - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

[image: this is the Firebase store]

```
public void checkUserFromDB(){
    String email = String.valueOf (Email.getText ()).trim ();
    String userPassword = String.valueOf (Password.getText ()).trim ();

    Query query = databaseReference.orderByChild ("email").equalTo (email);
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent (new ValueEventListener () {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                Email.setError(null);
                String userPasswordFromDB = snapshot.child("password").getValue(String.class);
                if (!Objects.equals(userPassword, userPasswordFromDB)) {
                    // Password matches
                    Password.setError(null);
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Tasks.class));
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // Password doesn't match
                    Password.setError("Password does not match.");
                    Password.requestFocus();
                }
            } else {
                Email.setError("Username aren't exists, please open a new account.");
                Email.requestFocus();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}
```

When I insert the email that exists and password that not, it goes to the `Tasks.class` - and when when I insert then right it takes me too to the `Tasks.class`. I tried everything nothing worked.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

Your code fails to handle that list, which you can do as shown in the documentation on [listening for a list of results](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events). In your case that'd be something like:

```
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent (new ValueEventListener () {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) { // 
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) { // 
                Email.setError(null);
                String userPasswordFromDB = snapshot.child("password").getValue(String.class);
                if (!Objects.equals(userPassword, userPasswordFromDB)) {
                    ...
```